# How does Kubernetes deal with node resource changes at run time?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm pretty new to k8s. How does k8s deal with node resource changes? For example, if some of the nodes are VMs and their resource assignment (cpu & memory) changes over time, does k8s control plane constantly monitor the computation resources available to each node and update its records?

Comment: You would probably have to either try it or trace the kubelet code to see for sure. But I would randomly guess that you have to restart the kubelet. Though it does check disk space continuously so maybe it does refresh the ram and cpu counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise, what do you mean to 'changes at run time'?
Did you mean that VM(node) is in cluster and you will turn off this VM, add new resources and turn on again?

If yes, please find some information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/) and some examples below:

***Minikube***

You are not able to change it. During creation of `Minikube` cluster, if you did not specify resources, it will automatically create cluster with `Minikube` name, 2 CPUs and 2048 RAM.

If you will specify Minikube resources for example:

`$ sudo minikube start --cpus=4 --memory=8192 -p minikube-name`

***Kubeadm***

Basically if mentioned VM is not Master, you just to have to turn off the VM, add resources and run it again. Kubeadm automatically will recognize that Node resources has been changed.

`$ kubectl describe node <node-name>`

```
$ kubectl describe node ubuntu18-slave
...
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.156.0.16
  Hostname:    ubuntu18-slave
Capacity:
 cpu:                2
 ephemeral-storage:  9983232Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             7652372Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                2
 ephemeral-storage:  9200546596
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             7549972Ki
 pods:               110
...
```

Added resources. Just turn off and turn on VM, without `kubelet` restart.

```
$ kubectl describe node ubuntu18-slave
...
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.156.0.16
  Hostname:    ubuntu18-slave
Capacity:
 cpu:                8
 ephemeral-storage:  9983232Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             30875684Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                8
 ephemeral-storage:  9200546596
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             30773284Ki
 pods:               110
...
```

***Cloud***

It depends from cloud providedr. I've tried to achieve this with `GKE`. 
I found only one way to do it. You just have to:
* Create a new `node_pool` with specific resources
* Add them to cluster
* Drain old node
* Delete old node

NOTE:

Please remember that before turn off VM (Node) you should [drain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) node you want to turn off.

**Monitoring**

To achieve resources usage in current time, create history of usage you can use some OpenSource or Paid software for it. All depends on your needs

- Kubernetes Dashboard
- Prometheus + Grafana
- Datadog
- Sysdig
  etc

However I would recommended you to use `Prometheus` as it is one of the most popular and you can find many tutorials online.
[Here](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics) you can find many useful information about metrics and prometheus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! By 'changes at run time', I mean adding/removing cores from VMs without turning them off, like ballooning

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) link very useful. To answer your question if K8s monitor resources, yes it does, as it has to make sure the resources required on a node are within the limits allowed for a resource, for e.g, CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add grafana to see these variations in more descriptive way or kubernetes dashboard can also be helpful.

You can also calculate the resource limits assigned to the pods of your applications, the nodes where they have been scheduled, thereby getting almost an approximate idea of the memory and cpu occupancy against the worker nodes.